# g++ linking issue

Tags: c++, c, linker, g++

I have a dependancy library (libfcgi) that I compiled with g++ (GCC v4.4 MinGW) using the following calls:

> g++ -Iinclude -c -O2 *.c
>   ar rcs ../libfcgi.a *.o

Now, my main project is built like so:

> g++ -Idependancies\libfcgi\include -Ldependancies -O2 -lfcgi *.cpp

g++ apparently finds libfcgi.a, but yet it fails to link to the following references:

> 'FCGI_printf'
>   'FCGI_Accept'

In the libfcgi sources, these functions are defined as follows:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
//...
DLLAPI int FCGI_printf(const char *format, ...);  
DLLAPI int FCGI_Accept(void);
//...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

where DLLAPI is nothing (as it isn't compiled as a shared library) and __cplusplus is defined (g++).

Looking at libfcgi.a, those functions are exported as '_FCGI_Accept' and '_FCGI_printf', so with an underscore in front. That's what seems to hinder g++ to find them.

I thought using export "C" would suffice to link to a C function in C++, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the same extern "C" definitions in your .cpp sources, then I think your problem is that the -lfcgi should follow the *.cpp in your command line:

```
g++ -Idependancies\libfcgi\include -Ldependancies -O2 *.cpp -lfcgi
```

Comment: You really thing that argument-order matters in this case?

Comment: Yes, it does. Libraries object files are included only of preceding object files have references to symbols in them.

Comment: Ha! Believe it or not, but combined with edgar.holleis' answer it actually works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your main-project, you tell the compiler to link C-functions, due to the `extern "C"`. It therefore expects unmangled symbol-names. You should therefore compile the fcgi-library with the C compiler, not the C++ compiler.

Comment: Ok, I tried compiling libfcgi with gcc, but the problem still remains :(